# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined trying to push information into object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
I am trying to add information to an object but I am getting an error (saying that property 'push' of undefined).

/*This is my object model:*/

export class Students {
  city: string;
  company: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  grades: [];
  id: string;
  lastName: string;
  pic: string;
  skill: string;
  open: boolean;
  tags: string[];
}
```

filteredStudents: Students[];

```
/*I have a form that gets the information user is typing.
f has the information and index_ has the index of the object.*/
```

sendForm(f: NgForm, index_: number) {

```
    if (f.invalid) {
      return
    }
    else {
/*storing the value of user input into "str variable"*/
      var str = f.value.inputTag;

/*Here is where the error happens. I am trying to store information into "tags" property of a specific student.*/
      this.filteredStudents[index_].tags.push(str);
    }
    f.reset();
  }
```

Please if you have any idea what is going on, please help me!
Please if you have any idea what is going on, please help me!
Please if you have any idea what is going on, please help me!

This errors appears into the console of google chrome.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but... `Students` (plural) should be `Student` (singular) because the class describes exactly one student and not a list of students

Answer (score 1):

I think its because this.filteredStudents isn't defined anywhere so you'll need to declare it as a hash w/ the key "tags" and the values as a list at the top of the controller somewhere.

```
this.filteredStudents = {
     tags: []
}
```

That should let you do 
`this.filteredStudents[tags].push('whatever').`

Also its a bit odd to have the _ at the end of index. I've seen internal functions have their names prefaced w/ _ back haven't seen it used at the end of function params.

Comment: I have defined filteredStudents... I just added to the above code.
Thank you anyways!

Comment: ```if(this.filteredStudents && this.filteredStudents[index]){ if (this.filteredStudents[index].tags){ /*push*/ } }``` Basically you're trying to push an item into a hash that doesn't exist yet. So the array is empty w no hash items w/ that key. So you have to check that the item is there, it has an object w the key 'tags', and then push it onto its list.

Answer (score 1):

You should update this:

```
  export class Students {
    ...
    tags = new Array<string>();
  }
```

Because tags: string[] this does not define the type.

**You must remember that the [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03) currently actually says, “Consider using an interface for data models.”**

In this case you can do something like this:

```
export interface Students {
    ...
    tags: string[];
}
```

And you can use it like this, for example:

```
    test: Students[] = new Array<Students>();

    const a = { city: 'My City', ..., tags: new Array<string>() };
    this.test.push( a );
    this.test[0].tags.push('Any string');
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to do it without modifying the class

```
(this.filteredStudents[index_].tags = this.filteredStudents[index_].tags || []).push(str)
```

or you can initialize the array tags

```
 export class Students {
          ...
          skill: string;
          open: boolean;
          tags = new Array<string>();
        }
```

and then

```
this.filteredStudents[index_].tags.push(str)
```